# How to make a div have the required height no matter what?

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a div fill up the page, but it seems to be only as long as the content I put in it. This is my css code:

```
.myDiv
{
    height:  30%;
}
```

What can I do to make it be that height whether the div is empty or has some content? (The content won't extend past the height I set here).

Comment: Try setting the `overflow` to some value other than `none`

Comment: Oh, and whatever answer/solution you choose: check it in IE7 or -dare I say- IE6 early, if you need to support those. They are notorious in their div height behavior :D

Comment: does your page have a doctype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using percentages so the height of the div depends directly on its parent. Make sure the parent has a height. If the direct parent is the body then:

```
body{
   height:100%;
}
```

If you know the exact height you want you for the div you should be using pixels like `height:300px;`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.  (I know you didn't ask about jQuery... but it is another option)

```
var height = $(document).height();
$('#myDiv').css('height', height);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/pNHzE/1/